# How to merge video flv and audio wav file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

I want to merge an audio .wav  with a video .flv using ffmpeg

Please suggest me how to achieve this. i am using this command on ubuntu 12 :

```
ffmpeg -i recod_audio.wav -i recod_ideo.flv -acodec libx264 -vcodec 
libx264  output.flv
```

but not getting success. i'm getting unnone tag libx264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is in `-acodec libx264`.

Type `ffmpeg -codecs` in cmd, and look in libx264:

```
EV     libx264         libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
```

You'll see "EV", where "E" means Encode, "V" means Video codec. There's no "A", which means that you can't use libx264 as audio codec. Consequently `-acodec libx264` is false.

Now the answer – try to use another audio codec, e.g. `aac`, the built-in AAC encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i recod_audio.wav -i recod_ideo.flv -c:a aac -strict -2 -c:v libx264 output.flv
```

Or MP3:

```
ffmpeg -i recod_audio.wav -i recod_ideo.flv -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 output.flv
```